# Find the intersection point of a plane and ray

Tags: code-golf, math, 3d

Given a ray with a point and a vector and a plane with a point and a normal vector to the plane. You have to find the intersection point of the plane and the ray..

So your job if you choose to accept is to write a shortest function that will do the job.

```
RULES:
The submission must be a complete program
And that's all

INPUT FORMAT:
x y z rx ry rz //gives the ray point and the ray vectors
x y z px py pz //gives the point on the plane and the vector normal to plane

OUTPUT FORMAT:
(x,y,z) //intersection point

Test Case:
2 3 4 0.577 0.577 0.577
7 1 3 1 0 0
(7,8,9)
```

The shortest codes in bytes win.

References: https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/raytrace/rayplane_intersection.htm  thanks [orlp](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4162/orlp) for the reference

Comment: then i think i should remove it.

Comment: Any specifications as to required precision? Say 3 decimal figures for example?

Comment: Do degenerate cases need to be handled? Ray parallel with the plane? Ray coincident with the plane? Any others???

Comment: Nope. Not needed to handle those..

Comment: Some test cases would be nice. Also, [relevant](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall00/cs426/lectures/raycast/sld017.htm).

Comment: A challenge like this could definitely use test cases; please add some!

Comment: It will be very helpful if the formulae involved are included in the question, else programmers will have to search for them.

Comment: @rnso i added a working function in my example. But Some one commented that my example is not a program but a function. So removed it.

Comment: @orlp this is my first question of the type. So I'm sorry to the community for my mistakes

Comment: @Lynn will add working testcases soon

Comment: I would strongly advice to [stop enforcing your very specific input/output rules.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8077/32352) They really don't add anything to the challenge.

Comment: ooh. thanks @sanchises for pointing it out.. My bad. Haven't seen those meta posts

Comment: I guess someone had ought to explain to you why nobody seemed to be inclined to follow your rules while still demanding strictness on some other parts :)

Comment: will try to follow the rules i discover on meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Mathematica, 20 bytes

Takes 4 lists as input. The dot product operator `.` has precedence over multiplication and division, so no more parentheses are needed.

```
#+#2(#3-#).#4/#2.#4&
```

Readable version:

```
x + v (r - x).n / v.n
```

where the arguments in order are `x` (ray point), `v` (ray direction), `r` (plane point), `n` (plane normal).

Comment: does it give output in desired format?

Comment: @KishanKumar If by desired format you mean with parentheses, then no. Neither is the input a bunch of numbers separated by spaces. Mathematica works in lists, which are enclosed by `{}` and separated by `,`.

Comment: No other answer shorter than this.. So, i have accepted this answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 107 bytes

Tested for all test cases (i.e. not tested at all)
Run with each input number on its own line on STDIN

```
perl -M5.010 plane.pl
0
1
0
0
0
1
3
3
1
0
0
1
^D
```

`plane.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$$_=<>for a..l;say$a+($t=($j*($g-$a)+$k*($h-$b)+$l*($i-$c))/($j*$d+$k*$e+$l*$f))*$d,$",$b+$t*$e,$",$c+$t*$f
```

This kind of problem is absolutely ***not*** a good match for perlgolf. Perl lacks vector operations and uses too many `$`s

Comment: `+1` for "for all test cases".

Comment: does it give output in desired format?

Comment: It prints the 3 coordinates on one line separated by spaces without `()`. Adding the `(,,)` takes 10 trivial bytes (just add the extra characters to the say)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>137</s> 157/102 bytes

Follows both input and output pattern. Program reads input from stdin. 157 bytes.

```
z=zipWith
main=do
[(p,r),(l,n)]<-map(splitAt 3.map read.words).lines<$>getContents
print$(\[a,b,c]->(a,b,c))$z(+)p$map(*(sum(z(*)n(z(-)l p))/sum(z(*)n r)))r
```

With an input file that has format `[[x,y,z],[rx,ry,rz],[x,y,z],[px,py,pz]]` and output of format `[x,y,z]` (102 bytes):

```
z=zipWith
main=do
[p,r,l,n]<-read<$>getContents
print$z(+)p$map(*(sum(z(*)n(z(-)l p))/sum(z(*)n r)))r
```

Comment: does it follow both output and input pattern...

Comment: The optional version did. I changed it to do it anyway, at the cost of 20 bytes.

Comment: well, remove the extra 20 bytes. no need to comply with my input pattern

Comment: It always complied with the input pattern - the output had different parentheses. I'll add an option that follows neither format.

Comment: Do the one that saves you most bytes..

Answer (score 1):

## R, 88 bytes

```
x=scan()
v=scan()
r=scan()
n=scan()
C=cat
C("(");C(x+v*sum((r-x)*n)/sum(v*n),sep=", ");C(")")
```

Adapted from the [Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95234/59052). Takes the following values from stdin, `x` (ray point), `v` (ray direction), `r` (plane point), `n` (plane normal). Outputs `(7, 8, 9)` for the test case.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 157 bytes

This could probably be shorter. The test case is subject to rounding errors, but otherwise it respects the challenge.

```
P=prompt;[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l]=(P()+' '+P()).split` `.map(e=>+e);alert('('+(a+(t=(j*(g-a)+k*(h-b)+l*(i-c))/(j*d+k*e+l*f))*d)+','+(b+t*e)+','+(c+t*f)+')')
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 93 bytes

```
(a,b,c,A,B,C,x,y,z,X,Y,Z)=>`(${t=X*(x-a)+Y*(y-b)+Z*(z-c)/(X*A+Y*B+Z*C),[a+t*A,b+t*B,c+t*C]})`
```

```js
f=
(a,b,c,A,B,C,x,y,z,X,Y,Z)=>`(${t=X*(x-a)+Y*(y-b)+Z*(z-c)/(X*A+Y*B+Z*C),[a+t*A,b+t*B,c+t*C]})`

console.log(f(2, 3, 4, 0.577350269, 0.577350269, 0.577350269, 7, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0))
```